# Where the main method thread will be created

Tags: java, multithreading

Hi I wanted to know how and where the main method will create thread for executing the application. whether it is extends thread or runnable.

Answer (score 1):

That is a nice question. When ever you execute your application JRE will create a thread for it. That thread will execute your `main()` method. It will be finished when the program reaches to the end. Obviously it should be the last thread to be ended. It extends `Thread` class and can be accessed by using like:

```
class ThreadTest {
    public static void main(String [] args){

    Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread();
    }
}
```

Comment: _Obviously it should be the last thread to be ended._ This is wrong, actually [threads can continue to run even after `main` thread has ended](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904745)

Comment: whether that main will extend thread class as u say.

Answer (score 0):

the main thread is the first thread to execute in a program.it is created by jvm.

Comment: How it will create by using extends thread or implements thread.

Comment: the main thread is called by jvm,when a program run the jvm check for main method and start execution,only child threads of main thread can be creaed using extends or runnable

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know how and where the main method will create thread for executing the application.

It doesn't.

What actually happens is that *something* creates the `main` thread, and the `main` thread then calls the `public static void main(String[])` method in the relevant class.

How this happens is implementation dependent.  If you really want to understand the details, the complete OpenJDK codebases for Java 6, 7 & 8 (beta) are available for download.

---

> whether it is extends thread or runnable.

It is not specified whether the main thread is an instance of `Thread` or a subclass of `Thread`.  It cannot (just) be `Runnable`, though a `Runnable` *could* be used to call the `main` method.

However, the `main` method can find out what the main thread's actual class is as follows:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args){

         Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
         System.out.println("Main thread class is " + t.getClass());
    }
}
```